# how to fastboot mode without Enable USB Debugging?

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, fastboot

I have a cellphone which I can't get access to the system, so Enable USB Debugging is not a option here. I need to factory reset this phone or upload a fresh firmeware to make it functional again, I figure it out that the way to do it is through Fastboot.

So, is there a way to unlock Fastboot mode in this phone without having to Enable USB Debugging?

Meizu Pro 6 Plus

Comment: you probably mean bootloader unlocking without enable OEM unlocking (usb-debugging is not related to fastboot). the answer is no. but you can use different official flash tools (if available) depending on chipset (Exynos, Qualcomm or Mediatek, all three possible for Meizu) or if you know google play account password (FRP lock) do a factory reset from recovery mode

Comment: Hey @alecxs I just checked here, the chipset for this meizu is Exynos 8890 Octa (14 nm)! What flash tools would you reccomend?

Comment: i am not aware of any [flash tool](https://androidmtk.com/category/tools). check meizu support or try samsung tools like heimdall/odin or maybe check that thread https://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/how-to/tutorial-restore-hard-bricked-lost-t3838461

Comment: If all your looking for is to Factory Reset then you can do that with fastboot without unlocking the bootloader.

Comment: @Sruly no, you can't do anything from fastboot if bootloader is locked. the only possible factory reset is *'fastboot flashing unlock'* but that most likely requires OEM unlocking (not sure about android version)

Comment: security hole on fastboot https://forum.xda-developers.com/smartwatch/moto-360/unlocking-bootloader-marshmallow-t3669098

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for your effort in trying to help me out, I've read all of those links you've sent me and I couldn't make it work... The solution would be MRT dongle, but this tool costs more than a new motherboard, and in my country (Brazil), that tool is not very common... I've tried a cracked one but it didn't work. Hahahaha Anyways, thanks for your insights!!